# Error in JQuery html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi please check my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#username_change_submit').click(function(){
        var htmlText = '<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href="javascript:;" id="reset_username">[Reset Username]</a> </p>
                        <input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;" onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                        <div id="email_status">&nbsp;</div>
                        <input type="button" id="guest_signup_submit" value="Create Account" style="font-size:13px;" disabled="true" onclick="Javascript:guest_register()">';
        $('#right-register').html(htmlText);
    }); 
});



<div id="right-register">
    <input type="button" value="Create Account" id="username_change_submit" name="username_change_submit">
</div>
```

Above code i am getting error.

I have little bit skill problem so i can't describe to you. Please check my screenshot.

[image]

Let me know the jquery error.

Comment: Because you are breaking the code with line-break use \n\ or clear the spaces...

Answer (score 2):

As i see here you didn't close the input tag. Put your input block like this;

```
<input />
```

Like;

```
<input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;" onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `\n\` at the end of every line for `htmlText` variable.

```
$(function(){
    $('#username_change_submit').click(function(){
        var htmlText = '<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href="javascript:;" id="reset_username">[Reset Username]</a></p>\n\
            <input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;" onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address">\n\
            <div id="email_status">&nbsp;</div><input type="button" id="guest_signup_submit" value="Create Account" style="font-size:13px;" disabled="true" onclick="Javascript:guest_register()">';
        $('#right-register').html(htmlText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are preparing a string in multiple lines, So browser will treats as there is no semicolon(;) at end of each line, so you are facing unterminated string literal error. You have to do it as shown below:

```
var htmlText = '<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href="javascript:;"';
htmlText += 'id="reset_username">[Reset Username]</a> </p>';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;"';
htmlText += 'onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address">';
htmlText += '<div id="email_status">&nbsp;</div>';
htmlText += '<input type="button" id="guest_signup_submit" value="Create Account"';
htmlText += 'style="font-size:13px;" disabled="true" onclick="Javascript:guest_register()">';
```

Answer (score 0):

### it warns about multi-line strings without escape characters(`\`).

#### You have to do it as shown below:

```
var htmlText = '<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href="javascript:;" id="reset_username">[Reset Username]</a> </p>\
                    <input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;" onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address">\
                    <div id="email_status">&nbsp;</div>\
                    <input type="button" id="guest_signup_submit" value="Create Account" style="font-size:13px;" disabled="true" onclick="Javascript:guest_register()">';
```

#### can do it as shown below, yet:

```
var htmlArr=[];
htmlArr.push('<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href="javascript:;" id="reset_username">[Reset Username]</a> </p>');
htmlArr.push('<input type="text" id="guest_email" style="font-size:13px;width:140px;" onkeyup="validate_email(this.value)" placeholder="E-mail Address">');
htmlArr.push('<div id="email_status">&nbsp;</div>');
htmlArr.push('<input type="button" id="guest_signup_submit" value="Create Account" style="font-size:13px;" disabled="true" onclick="Javascript:guest_register()">');

var htmlText = htmlArr.join('');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var htmlText = "<p>Learnphp has been reserved for you.<br><a href='javascript:;'" + "id='reset_username'>[Reset Username]</a> </p>" + "<input type='text' id='guest_email' style='font-size:13px;width:140px;'" + "onkeyup='validate_email(this.value)' placeholder='E-mail Address'>" + "<div id='email_status'>&nbsp;</div>" + "<input type='button' id='guest_signup_submit' value='Create Account'" + "style='font-size:13px;' disabled='true' onclick='Javascript:guest_register()'/>";
```